# How to scan words from console and store somewhere (Java)?

Tags: java, input

I am trying to get input from user, in each line user enters two words and later i will be comparing those two words. The program needs to accept multiple lines which means more than 1 comparisons. I need to know how we get input from user for multiple lines. (the input is stored in txt file and basically will be copy and pasted in console as if user is inputing) **This is for Java**
*Thanks*

Comment: _"This is for Java"_ So why did you tag it with [tag:javascript]?

Comment: sorry i am new to programming and java, sorry once again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hasNext()` function in Scanner object

Example:

```
public static void main(String [] args) { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Write something ");
    while(scan.hasNext()) { 
        /* while there is more input to read do something */
    }
}
```